# ASP.NET Core 5 - Session variables lifetime vs SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, session-variables, asp.net-core-5.0

ASP.NET Core 5.0.

My application stores some values in session variables. Sometimes (e.g.: when the application server is restarted) the user is stil signed in (`SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` returns `true`) while session variables are `null`.

What is the correct way to make it consistent and/or show the login page when a certain session variable does not exist?

Comment: You can of course try to fix it with a simple test: `if session["someVariable"] == null then redirect to login page`, or you can use e.g. cookie based TempData.

Comment: Session and authentication cookies are unrelated

Comment: @davidfowl yes, I know they are unrelated. That's why I'm asking what's the proper way to make sure that session data expiration is consistent with the authentication (or viceversa).